# Oracle: Special characters filter with few exceptions

Tags: regex, oracle, translate, regexp-replace

I need some quick help.

I want to filter the input string and remove special characters except space( ), period(.), comma(,), hyphen(-), ampersand(&) and apostrophe(').

I am using below but it's filtering out everything except period(.) and comma(,).

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('*Bruce*-*Martha*-&-*Thomas%* *Wyane''s* *Enterprises* ([#Pvt,Ltd.])', '[^0-9A-Za-z,.'' ]', '')  
FROM dual;
```

Input String: `*Bruce*-*Martha*-&-*Thomas%* *Wyane's* *Enterprises* ([#Pvt,Ltd.])`

What I am expecting: `Bruce-Martha-&-Thomas Wyane's Enterprises Pvt,Ltd.`

What I am getting: `BruceMarthaThomas Wyane's Enterprises Pvt,Ltd.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('*Bruce*-*Martha*-&-*Thomas%* *Wyane''s* *Enterprises* ([#Pvt,Ltd.])', '[^&0-9A-Za-z,.'' -]+', '') FROM dual
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQnZpk/1)

The `[^&0-9A-Za-z,.'' -]+` pattern will match one or more occurrences of any char but `&`, ASCII letter, digit, comma, dot, single apostrophe, space and hyphen.

To support any whitespace, replace the literal space with `[:space:]`:

```
'[^&0-9A-Za-z,.''[:space:]-]+'
```

Comment: See [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d7e4/1), too, yielding `Bruce-Martha-&-Thomas Wyane's Enterprises Pvt,Ltd.`

Comment: Thanks for checking this. I tried the query you gave but it asks me substitution value because of ampersand used.